# Function returns value in hex

Tags: c++, return, hex

I made a function to double every other digit of a number, but for some reason it converts the in to hex before returning. I checked, and that hex is accurate to an actual number, but how do I get it to stop returning hex? Here's the code.

```cpp
unsigned long long* Luhn_Algorigthem::double_every_other_value(unsigned long long int in) {
    unsigned long long int* out = new unsigned long long;
    int counter = 10;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < std::to_string(in).length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) { //Is even
            counter * 10;
            out += (unsigned long long)((in % counter) * 2);
        }
        else { //Is odd
            out += (unsigned long long)(std::to_string(in).at(i));
        }
    }

    doubled_val = (unsigned long long)out;
    return (unsigned long long*)33;
    delete out;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't "return hex". It returns a pointer that might be printed as hex-value.

Comment: It is returning hex, I'm not talking about what it represents, but the value is in hexadecimal.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `return (unsigned long long*)33;`?

Comment: I changed the number to see if the issue was only with the variable I was returning

Comment: Do you understand what `return (unsigned long long*)33;` does?

Comment: @ComyarD No. You can't return hex. It's just not possible. Numbers are stored in binary format. A pointer is just a number. You can only _print_ it as hex value. Not that `return (unsigned long long*)33;` would make any sense, I suppose it's for testing only?

Comment: I believe that it returns 33 while casting it to an unsigned long long*

Comment: Why does this return a pointer to an `unsigned long long` instead of just and `unsigned long long` directly? (That makes the function harder to use properly.) Why are you trying to add values to the pointer itself via `out += (unsigned long long)`? Did you know that any code after the `return` will not be executed? So your `delete out;` isn't executing - but even if it was, and your intend was to return `out` then you would presumably be returning something that's already been deleted. You should really just refactor this to not use pointers at all.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish thanks, that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheUndedFish helped solve the problem for me, I ended up just getting rid of the pointer, and used the `doubled val` variable for it instead without allocating memory to the heap. This is the updated code:

```cpp
unsigned long long int Luhn_Algorigthem::double_every_other_value(unsigned long long int in) {
    //unsigned long long int* out = new unsigned long long;
    int counter = 10;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < std::to_string(in).length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) { //Is even
            counter * 10;
            doubled_val += (in % counter) * 2;
        }
        else { //Is odd
            doubled_val += std::to_string(in).at(i);
        }
    }
    //delete out;
    return doubled_val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned and long are type modifiers (like adjectives without a noun), have you tried `unsigned long int` for explicit type casting?

Comment: Hi, I can't add the ** before the int, but isn't long already equivalent with int?

Comment: The ** were just to bold "int" in my comment to emphasize the change. I believe you have to explicitly say `int`, not just `long`. They are similar but long is not an actual type, in this case, just a modifier